# Xamarin oauth through WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin, web, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have been trying to implement google OAuth in Xamarin Forms App for a couple days. I have a pretty simple `XAML` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Google.ViewModels"
         x:Class="Google.MainPage">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
    <WebView Source="{Binding OAuthRequestUrl}" 
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

And `ViewModel` :

```
public string OAuthRequestUrl 
{ 
    get 
    {
        string oauthReuest = string.Format(
            "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&response_type={2}&scope={3}", 
            clientId, 
            redirectUrl, 
            responceType, 
            scope);
        return oauthReuest;
    } 
}
```

But after webview has been initialised I got `403: disalloed_useragent`.
Initially I had used Web Client Credentials and OAuth via browser + postman completed successfully.

[image]

Comment: you need to open the auth window on the installed browser on the device. You cant open it in a webview.

Comment: @DaImTo well, i used OAuth2Authenticator in ViewModel like [this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1398937/oauth2authenticator-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object), but catching `Object reference exception`

Comment: I have an example of this that i did for a client three years ago. I haven't touched it since. Its based off of the example found here.   [MainActivity.cs](https://github.com/Pujolsluis/GoogleAuthXamarinSample/blob/997f30b7e0fe8967f2db9ed120528ac5ffe8eb4f/GoogleLogin/GoogleLogin/GoogleLogin.Android/MainActivity.cs)  if that link doesnt help let me know and i will see if i cant either put this up on git or turn it into a tutorial for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the User Agent of the WebView control.

Unfortunately, this is not currently supported, but you will find some workarounds here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8432

Comment: But it look like some kind of crutch. I don't want to invent the wheel. Is there some normal way to use Xamarin + OAuth ?

Comment: It's not really a crutch, but it is a side-effect of using the WebView control in this context. It is possible to do OAuth in other ways as [documented here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) but I have not personally tried any of them.